# After forcing Bleach Bit to stop, now Lubuntu cannot boot v14.04

Tags: boot, bleachbit

I was running Bleach Bit but got tired that it didn't finish, so I forced it to stop by pressing the boot button. After that, I started again the laptop, it keeps on trying to boot but it doesn't. The laptop has Lubuntu.

Comment: Any error messages (maybe press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot splash)? How does "keeps on trying to boot" look like? Did you press briefly or did you hold until the laptop powered off?

Answer (score 0):

Using safe mode or a boot CD, make sure the hard disk is not full.

Then, make sure you are using the BleachBit version 1.2 (which has a bug fix related to this) or later.  The latest right now is 1.5.2.